# SwiftUI Picker with style = navigationLink causes 100% CPU usage

Tags: swiftui

I have a `NavigationStack` that contains some `View`, which itself contains a `Picker` with `.pickerStyle(.navigationLink)`.

When clicking on the `Picker` in the emulator, the cpu usage spikes to 100% and becomes unresponsive.

It does not happen when not using `.pickerStyle(.navigationLink)`

[image]

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  test
//
//  Created by Anon on 1/4/23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct Contact : Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
    static var preview : [Contact] = [
        Contact(id: UUID().uuidString, name: "John"),
        Contact(id: UUID().uuidString, name: "Mary")
    ]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let types : [String] = ["work","home"]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(){
            List(Contact.preview){
                contact in
                NavigationLink(contact.name, value: contact)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Contact.self){
                contact in
                Form{
                    Picker(selection: .constant("work"), label: Text("Type")){
                        ForEach(types, id: \.self) { item in
                            Text(item)
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(.navigationLink)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: can confirm. But if you put the picker in a subview everything is fine.

Comment: the issue is still here, to put the picker in a subview doesn't always work. It looks like there is some swiftui bug with binding picker's selection.

Answer (score 2):

This is an invalidation bug in SwiftUI and will happen if you have the following:

- `.navigationDestination()` with a variable capture in the closure (`types` in your code)
- State based navigation inside the destination view (`.navigationLink` picker in your example, but will also happen with non-value `NavigationLink`)

The workaround is to extract the contents of the trailing closure (`Form` in your code) to its own named `View` struct. This can take whatever captured variables as constructor parameters.

This seems to work because SwiftUI can see that this view is the same and not re-evaluate it’s body on child navigation.

Comment: Can confirm this fix helped me too, thanks!

Comment: It's extreme that bugs like this can happen and stay in releases...